# Method to find $\sin (2\pi/7)$

Tags: trigonometry

I just thought a way to find $\sin\frac{2π}{7}$.

Considering the equation $x^7=1$

$⇒(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=0$

$⇒(x-1)[(x+\frac1 x)^3+(x+\frac1 x)^2-2(x+\frac1 x)-1]=0$

We can then get the 7 solutions of x, but the steps will be very complicated, especially when solving cubic equation, and expressing x as a+bi. The imaginary part of the second root of x will be $\sin\frac{2π}{7}$.

Besides this troublesome way, are any other approach? Thank you.

Comment: It is an approach that works very nicely with $5$. With $7$, not so good, though it is a good way to prove that the regular $7$-gon is not Euclidean constructible.  I think that if you use the Cardano formula, you end up needing a cube root of a complex number, and that cube root cannot be found without knowing the required sine or a close relative.

Comment: needs to be -1 at the end in the square brackets. Edited.

Comment: The other bad news is that your cubic $u^3 + u^2 - 2 u - 1$ has three irrational real roots, which means there is no pretty way to separate the real and imaginary parts in Cardano's formula, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Comment: @ André Nicolas: I will have 3 value of $x+1/x$, which leads x to be square root of complex number, and can be reduced to the form a+bi.

Comment: jasoncube, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_formula#Cardano.27s_method  I'm afraid it is cube roots of complex numbers, not square roots alone.

Comment: @ Will Jagy, You're right...

Comment: +1: Might I recommend that you study algebraic number theory some time in the future. This type of calculations show up inside cyclotomic fields.

Comment: This is the second time in my life heard of cyclotomic fields. XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for laughs, we can at least in principle compute $\cos{(\pi/7)}$ by observing that

$$\sin{\frac{3 \pi}{7}} = \sin{\frac{4 \pi}{7}}$$

Using a combination of double-angle forumlae, we end up with a cubic equation for $\cos{(\pi/7)}$:

$$8 \cos^3{\frac{\pi}{7}} - 4 \cos^2{\frac{\pi}{7}} - 4 \cos{\frac{\pi}{7}}+1=0$$

This equation has one real solution which is $\cos{(\pi/7)}$.  The bad news is that the expression is unwieldy at best:

$$\cos{\frac{\pi}{7}}=\frac{1}{6} \left(1+\frac{7^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+3 i\sqrt{3}\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{3}\right)}\right)$$

The imaginary part of this expression is of course zero.  The real part, however, ends up being expressed in terms of a sine and cosine of another angle, and I think the point of an exercise like this is to not do that.  Anyway, I hope this adds to the discussion above.

Comment: I considered figuring out how to derive this equation with double/triple angle sine/cosine formulas. +1 for saving me the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Target=> $\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$

set $$\sqrt[7]{1}=ζ^{k}_{7}$$ $$ζ^{k}_{7}=e^{\frac{2ki\pi}{7}}$$ as seventh roots of unity
so, the statements applies
$$ζ^{1}_{7}+ζ^{2}_{7}+ζ^{3}_{7}+ζ^{4}_{7}+ζ^{5}_{7}+ζ^{6}_{7}+1=0$$
$$ζ^{k}_{7}=\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}\pm i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$ζ^{-k}_{7}=\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}\mp i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$ζ^{k}_{7}+ζ^{-k}_{7}=2\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$ζ^{k}_{7}-ζ^{-k}_{7}=\pm2i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$ζ^{2k}_{7}-2+ζ^{-2k}_{7}=-4\sin^2\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$2\cos\frac{4k\pi}{7}-2=-4\sin^2\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{2\cos\frac{4k\pi}{7}-2}=\pm2i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
the 
$$ζ^{1}_{7}+ζ^{2}_{7}+ζ^{3}_{7}+ζ^{4}_{7}+ζ^{5}_{7}+ζ^{6}_{7}+1=0$$
gives us irreducible cubic polynomial
$$t^3+t^2-2t-1=0$$
where
$$t_{k}=2\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
applying lagrange resolvent for cubic
$$-1=t_{1}+t_{2}+t_{3}$$
$$r_1=t_{1}+ζ^{1}_{3}t_{2}+ζ^{2}_{3}t_{3}$$
$$r_2=t_{1}+ζ^{2}_{3}t_{2}+ζ^{1}_{3}t_{3}$$
where $ζ^{2}_{3}$ is the cuberoot of unity, Applying Discrete Fourier Transform inverse
$$3t_{1}=-1+r_1+r_2$$
$$3t_{2}=-1+ζ^{2}_{3}r_1+ζ^{1}_{3}r_2$$
$$3t_{3}=-1+ζ^{1}_{3}r_1+ζ^{2}_{3}r_2$$
on the action of lagrange method, lagrange resolvent gives
$$r^3_1=7\left(3ζ^{1}_{3}-1\right)$$
$$r^3_2=7\left(3ζ^{2}_{3}-1\right)$$
now...
$$r_1=\sqrt[3]{7\left(3ζ^{1}_{3}-1\right)}$$
$$r_2=\sqrt[3]{7\left(3ζ^{2}_{3}-1\right)}$$
$$ζ^{1}_{3}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
$$ζ^{2}_{3}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
$$r_1=\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}$$
$$r_1=\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}$$
$$3t_{1}=-1+r_1+r_2$$
$$3t_{2}=-1+ζ^{2}_{3}r_1+ζ^{1}_{3}r_2$$
$$3t_{3}=-1+ζ^{1}_{3}r_1+ζ^{2}_{3}r_2$$
$$3t_{1}=-1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}$$
$$3t_{2}=-1+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}$$
$$3t_{3}=-1+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}$$
$$2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}=\frac{-1+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}}{3}$$
$$2\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}=\frac{-1+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}}{3}$$
$$2\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}=\frac{-1+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}}{3}$$
$$\sqrt{2\cos\frac{4k\pi}{7}-2}=\pm2i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{t_{2k}-2}=2i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{t_{2}-2}=2i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{t_{4}-2}=2i\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{t_{6}-2}=2i\sin\frac{6\pi}{7}$$
$$t_{4}=t_{3}$$
$$t_{6}=t_{1}$$
$$\sqrt{t_{2}-2}=2i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{-1+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}}{3}
-2}=2i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{-7+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}}{3}}=2i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{3\left(-7+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}\right)}{9}}=2i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3\left(-7+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}\right)}}{3}=2i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$
so, 
$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}=\frac{\sqrt{-3\left(-7+\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1+3\sqrt{-3}\right)}+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}\left(1-3\sqrt{-3}\right)}\right)}}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309271/two-trigonometric-identities-using-complex-variables/309301#309301) or Point#$24$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html) ,

$\sin 7x=7s-56s^3+112s^5-64s^7$ where $s=\sin x$

If $\sin 7x=0,7x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer.

So, $x=\frac{n\pi}7$ where $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$

So, the roots of $7s-56s^3+112s^5-64s^7=0--->(1)$ are $\sin\frac{n\pi}7$ where $n=0,1,2,\cdots 5,6$

So, the roots of $64s^6-112s^4+56s^2-7=0--->(2)$ are $\sin\frac{n\pi}7$ where $n=1,2,\cdots 5,6$

So, the roots of $64t^3-112t^2+56t-7=0 --->(3)$ are $\sin^2\frac{n\pi}7$ where $n=1,2,4$ or $3,5,6$ as $\sin \frac{(7-r)\pi}7=\sin(\pi-\frac{r\pi}7)=\sin\frac{r\pi}7$

If we choose $n=1,2,4$ observe that $\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7-\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7=2\sin\frac{\pi}7\cos\frac{3\pi}7>0$ (Using $\sin^2A-\sin^2B=\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)$)

Similarly, $\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7-\sin^2\frac{\pi}7>0$

So, $\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7>\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7>\sin^2\frac{\pi}7$

Using [Cardano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method), we can solve the Cubic equation $(3)$