# Please help me with factorisation of $64x^6-112x^4+56x^2-7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Is it possible to write $$64x^6-112x^4+56x^2-7$$ in linear factors?

If so, what are they?

(Finding it really difficult to ask this question!!)

Comment: As a possible start, substitute $u = x^2$ and reduce it to the cubic $64u^3 - 112u^2 + 56 u - 7$.

Comment: Are you dealing with $\sin\frac{r\pi}7$ for integer $r$? If yes, see my answers here( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470614/find-the-value-of-textrmcosec2-left-frac-pi7-right-textrmcosec2-left) and   here(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311781/method-to-find-sin-2-pi-7). Also have  a look into http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi7.html

Comment: Have you learned Eisenstein's Criterion?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), after a bit of testing, we see that there are no rational roots. So you won't find "easily accessible" factors of the form $x-r$, where $ r \in \mathbb {Q} $. Also, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6x%5E6-112x%5E4%2B56x%5E2-7).

Comment: This is the hard way.