# Trigonometry problem on product of trig functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Questions:**

1. $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{7}\cos\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\cos\dfrac{3\pi}{7}=?$
2. $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{7}\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\sin\dfrac{3\pi}{7}=?$
3. $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{7}\tan\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\tan\dfrac{3\pi}{7}=?$

**Approach**: 
If $x=\dfrac{\pi}{7}\implies 7x=\pi\implies 4x=\pi-3x\implies \sin 4x = \sin 3x$.Upon expansion, $$8cos^3x-4cos²x-4cosx+1=0$$

> "$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{7}, \cos \dfrac{3\pi}{7}, \cos \dfrac{5\pi}{7}$will satisfy this cubic."

**Note: I'm not able to understand the above line. Why do these values satisfy this cubic and how did we get these values?**

These are therefore the roots of the cubic, and their product is: 
$$\cos\dfrac{\pi}{7}\cos\dfrac{3\pi}{7}\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{7}=\dfrac{-1}{8}$$

Finally,
$\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{7} = \cos\left(\pi-\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)=-\cos \dfrac{2\pi}{7}$. Replacing this in (1) gives $$\cos\dfrac{\pi}{7}\cos\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\cos\dfrac{3\pi}{7}=\dfrac{1}{8}$$

How can we apply this concept to find the values of

2. $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{7}\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\sin\dfrac{3\pi}{7}?$
3. $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{7}\tan\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\tan\dfrac{3\pi}{7}?$

I'm not able to form the equations for these two problems. Please Help. .

Comment: It's a genuine question, I don't understand why people down vote it.  How can we be so arrogant?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your question was poorly formatted without much evidence – as far as I can perceive – of effort from you. I don't see why downvoting is necessarily a display of arrogance.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on formatting. I've seen some users who deliberately downvote others' question. A problem which seems easy to one can be difficult for others. We all are here to share knowledge, learn and help each other. I tried to understand this question many times but I was not able to understand that line ( see note ). Thanks Mathlove for your awesome explanation. It's my first question on stack exchange and I've not used Latex much, before. I'm learning it. Thanks again to all for your kind help. And Sorry if someone get hurt from my comment.

Comment: Such a interesting problem and what a solution! Can you share where did you find this I am looking for good math problem sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=\pi/7$.

We know $x=\cos a$ is a root of $8x^3-4x^2-4x+1=0$. This is because $$3a+4a=\pi\Rightarrow \sin(3a)=\sin(4a)$$ as you wrote.

Now, note that $3\cdot 3a+4\cdot 3a=3\pi\Rightarrow \sin(3\cdot 3a)=\sin(4\cdot 3a)$. This can be done for $5a$ as well. This is why $\cos (3a),\cos (5a)$ satisfy the cubic.

For 3, since $3a+4a=\pi\Rightarrow \tan(3a)+\tan(4a)=0$, we have
$$\frac{\tan a+\tan(2a)}{1-\tan a\tan(2a)}+\frac{2\tan(2a)}{1-\tan^2(2a)}=0,$$
i.e.
$$\tan a+3\tan(2a)-3\tan a\tan^2(2a)-\tan^3(2a)=0.$$
Setting $x=\tan a$ gives us
$$x+\frac{6x}{1-x^2}-\frac{12x^3}{(1-x^2)^2}-\frac{8x^3}{(1-x^2)^3}=0,$$
i.e.
$$x^6-21x^4+35x^2-7=0.$$

Here, note that $x=\tan a,\tan(2a),\tan(3a)$ are roots of this equation by the similar argument above. Hence, $\tan^2(ka)\ (k=1,2,3)$ are roots of
$$x^3-21x^2+35x-7=0.$$
So, we have
$$\tan^2a\tan^2(2a)\tan^2(3a)=7\Rightarrow \tan a\tan(2a)\tan(3a)=\sqrt 7.$$

Finally, we have
$$\sin a\sin(2a)\sin(3a)=\cos a\cos(2a)\cos (3a)\times \tan a\tan(2a)\tan(3a)=\frac{\sqrt 7}{8}.$$

Comment: Thankyou, thankyou very much.

Comment: @RaviKumar: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin\left[7\left(\pm\dfrac{u\pi}7\right)\right]=0$ for any integer $u$

If $\sin7x=0,7x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies x=\dfrac{n\pi}7$ where $n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\pmod7$

For $f(c)=8c^3-4c^2-4c+1=0$

$f'(c)=24c^2-8c-4=4(6c^2-2c-1)$

As $f'(c)=0,f(c)=0$ don't have any root in common, $f(c)=0$ does not have Repeated Root.

As $\cos(-A)=\cos A,\cos\left(\pm\dfrac{r\pi}7\right),r=1,2,3$ will be the roots of $f(c)=0$

---

For the Sine product, I would recommend [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311781/method-to-find-sin-2-pi-7/311819#311819)

and use $\sin(\pi-B)=\sin B$

---

For tangent Product, I would recommend method applied in
[Sum of tangent functions where arguments are in specific arithmetic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series) and [Prove that $\cot^2{(\pi/7)} + \cot^2{(2\pi/7)} + \cot^2{(3\pi/7)} = 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265229/prove-that-cot2-pi-7-cot22-pi-7-cot23-pi-7-5/265308#265308)

to find  the roots of $t^6-21t^4+35t^2-7=0--->(2)$ are $\tan\frac{r\pi}7$ where $r=1,2,3,4,5,6$

and use $\tan(\pi-C)=-\tan C$