# How to prove the trigonometric equality $\tan(\pi/7) \tan(2\pi/7) \tan(3\pi/7)= \sqrt 7$?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to prove this equality holds:

$$\tan\big(\frac{\pi}7\big)  \tan\big(\frac{2\pi}7\big)  \tan\big(\frac {3\pi}7\big)= \sqrt 7.$$

Please help me.  Thanks.

Comment: There's a helpful identity here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Identities_without_variables

Comment: This already has an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182103/trigonometry-problem-on-product-of-trig-functions)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823819/if-alpha-frac2-pi7-then-the-find-the-value-of-tan-alpha-tan2-alpha/824178#824178

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{equation}
\tan \frac{\pi}{7}  \tan \frac{2\pi}{7}  \tan \frac {3\pi}{7} = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{7}  \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}  \sin \frac {3\pi}{7}}{{\cos \frac{\pi}{7}  \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}  \cos \frac {3\pi}{7}}}
\end{equation}
Now, it is trivial to see that
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{3 \pi}{7}= \frac{\pi}{7} + \frac{2 \pi}{7} = \frac{\pi}{7}+ \frac{\pi}{7} + \frac{\pi}{7}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, concentrating on the numerator and using the identity
\begin{equation}
\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta
\end{equation}
We find
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin \frac{\pi}{7}  \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}  \sin \frac {3\pi}{7} &=& \sin \frac{\pi}{7}\left(\sin \frac{\pi}{7}\cos \frac{\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{\pi}{7}\sin \frac{\pi}{7} \right) \sin \frac {3\pi}{7}\\
                                                              &=& 2\sin^{2} \frac{\pi}{7}  \cos \frac{\pi}{7}  \sin \frac {3\pi}{7} 
\end{eqnarray}
Now repeat this process for the term on $3 \pi/7$ and continue into the denominator and you should be ok.

Comment: well, this will not work dude, would you please do the rest?

Comment: @user224013 I believe the links supplied sufficiently answer the question.