# Find the value of $\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}\sin\frac{\pi}{14}\sin\frac{3\pi}{14}\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $$\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}\sin\frac{\pi}{14}\sin\frac{3\pi}{14}\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}$$

$$\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}\sin\frac{\pi}{14}\sin\frac{3\pi}{14}\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}$$
$$=\sin\frac{2\pi}{14}\sin\frac{4\pi}{14}\sin\frac{6\pi}{14}\sin\frac{\pi}{14}\sin\frac{3\pi}{14}\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}$$
$$=\sin\frac{\pi}{14}\sin\frac{2\pi}{14}\sin\frac{3\pi}{14}\sin\frac{4\pi}{14}\sin\frac{5\pi}{14}\sin\frac{6\pi}{14}$$

How can I compute $$\prod\limits_{r=1}^{n}\sin\frac{r\pi}{c}$$

Comment: If $c=2N$ and $n=N-1$ then from the Chebyshev polynomials you get the formula $$\prod_{r=1}^{N-1}\sin\frac{r\pi}{2N}=\frac{\sqrt{N}}{2^{N-1}}.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be seen as an instance of the well-known identity:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{2n}{2^n} \tag{1} $$
that for $n=14$ gives:
$$ \left[\prod_{k=1}^{6}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{14}\right)\right]^2 = \frac{14}{2^{13}} \tag{2}$$
from which:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{6}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{14}\right) = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{64}}.\tag{3} $$

Comment: Can you provide a link to read more about that identity?

Comment: @AdityaDev: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1

Answer (score 5):

By the basic properties of [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) the numbers $x_k=\sin(k\pi/14)$, $k=-6,-5,\ldots,5,6, k\neq0$ are the twelve zeros of the polynomial
$$
\frac{U_{13}(x)}x=8192 x^{12}-24576 x^{10}+28160 x^8-15360 x^6+4032 x^4-448 x^2+14.
$$

By the usual relations (aka Vieta relations) of the zeros of a polynomial and its coefficients it follows that
$$
A=\prod_{k=-6..6, k\neq0}x_k=\frac{14}{8192}=\frac{7}{2^{12}}.
$$

Because sine is known to be an odd function, the products $N=\prod_{k=-6}^{-1}x_k$ and $P=\prod_{k=1}^6x_k$ are equal. You are asking about the product
$P$. It is clearly a positive number, so from the equation
$$A=NP=P^2=\frac{7}{2^{12}}
$$
we can solve
$$
P=\frac{\sqrt7}{2^6}.
$$

The method generalizes for other products of sines as long as you take the product of ALL the numbers $\sin (k\pi/(2N))$, $k=1,2,\ldots,N-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Use $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2-A\right)=\cos A$ and $\sin2B=2\sin B\cos B$

to find the product $$=\dfrac{\sin2t\sin4t\sin6t}8$$ where $7t=\pi$

Now use [Method to find $\sin (2\pi/7)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311781/method-to-find-sin-2-pi-7/311819#311819), to find

$$\sin2t\sin4t\sin6t=\sqrt{\dfrac7{64}}$$

Comment: See  also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265229/prove-that-cot2-pi-7-cot22-pi-7-cot23-pi-7-5